# Prove that $f: \Bbb R\to\Bbb R:x\mapsto x^3-3x$ is surjective

Tags: functions

How to prove that $$f: \Bbb R\to\Bbb R:x\mapsto x^3-3x$$  is surjective? By expressing $x$ in terns of $y$? I am so confused right now.

Comment: I wouldn't do it like that. How are you with real analysis? Are you comfortable with limits and the intermediate value theorem?

Comment: Show that the function tends to $\infty$ as $x \to \infty$, and tends to $-\infty$ as $x \to -\infty$, and note that the function is continuous.

Comment: Every odd degree polynomial on $\Bbb R$ is surjective.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown, can you justify why?

Comment: @TheoBendit I am completely a beginner of real analysis...I learned a bit about intermediate value theorem in Calculus

Comment: @Decaf-Math: Every odd degree polynomial with positive leading coefficient satisfies the conditions in angryavian's comment (the negative case is symmetric).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let me say that finding a value $x$ such that $y = x^3 - 3x$ is perfectly possible to do, but really horrible. Cardano's method is how you find roots of a cubic, but the formula that comes out the end is far, far worse than the quadratic formula. I would strongly recommend against using this, unless you really need a precise, specific value of $x$ such that $y = x^3 - 3x$.

Let $f(x) = x^3 - 3x$, and fix some $y \in \mathbb{R}$. Since $f$ is a continuous function, it suffices to find $a$ and $b$ such that
$$f(a) < y < f(b)$$
because, by the intermediate value theorem, there must be some $x$ between $a$ and $b$ such that $f(x) = y$ (which is what we need to prove surjectivity).

To find an appropriate $b$, consider first the possibility the $y \le 2$. If $y < 2$, then $f(2) = 2$, so we can just pick $b = 2$. (If $y = 2$, then just outright choose $x = 2$, and be done with it!)

Otherwise, suppose $y > 2$. Note that, for $x \ge 2$, we have $x^3 \ge 4x$, so
$$f(x) = x^3 - 3x \ge 4x - 3x = x.$$
Thus, if we just choose $b = y + 1$, then $b > 3 \ge 2$, so
$$f(b) \ge b = y + 1 > y$$
as required.

We have our upper estimate $b$. To find a lower estimate of $a$, we can use the symmetry of the function. Note that $f$ is odd, that is, $f(-x) = -f(x)$ for all $x$. Therefore, by the reasoning above, if $y = -2$, we can use $x = -2$. If $y > -2$, then set $a = -2$. If $y < -2$, then setting $a = y - 1$ will work.

Either which way, we now have $a$ and $b$ such that $f(a) < f(y) < f(b)$. Because $f$ is continuous, the intermediate value theorem kicks in, and so there exists some $x$ between $a$ and $b$ such that $f(x) = y$.

Answer (score 2):

The way the question is phrased right now is not quite clear, as surjectivity is a property of functions.
Precisely, you mean to say:

> How do I show that the function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x)=x^{3}-3x$ is surjective?

A function $f$ is *surjective* if for every element $y$ in its codomain, you can find an element $x$ in the domain such that $f(x)=y$.
In your case, both the domain and codomain are $\mathbb{R}$.

**Hint**: Note that $f(x) \rightarrow \pm \infty$ as $x \rightarrow \pm \infty$ and $f$ is continuous.

Comment: This seems like it should be a comment, rather than an answer, especially since the part that helps the asker move forward is a hint that was already given in the comments.

Comment: You're probably right. I had already written it up while the comments were being posted. Though I think the definition of surjectivity is useful to the OP, since I am not certain if they are aware that it is a property of functions.

Comment: Referring to LordShark's comment.y_0 = x^3-3x has at least 1 real root.Complex roots occur in pairs.That does the trick I presume.

Answer (score 0):

Fix some $y \in \mathbb{R}$. Notice that the LHS of the equation $x^3 - 3x - y = 0$ is a non-constant polynomial with real coefficients (as $y$ is a constant); therefore, by the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra, the set of possible solutions for $x$ is nonempty and a subset of $\mathbb{R}$. This proves surjectivity.